# Who owns a php exec tar extracted file?

Tags: php, linux, exec, file-permissions

As far as file permissions are concerned, when you use a php script to unzip a tar file, who is the "owner" user of the files created?

I'm wondering if its my ftp user because I uploaded the script file? Or does apache own the file? I know their are flags to be set to preserve the original permissions which I don't want (files where created and archived by someone else). I want my user to be the creater/owner of the files.

PS Its a cloud environment.
Below is the code I uploaded. I executed by visiting the page in a browser. I can change file permissions in Dreamweaver... Does that mean I am owner?

`exec('wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz');`
`exec('tar -xzvf latest.tar.gz');`

Answer (score 5):

Most likely, if run from apache, the user that apache is running as.

Comment: There are lots of scenarios where this is not most likely :)

Answer (score 3):

Whatever user runs PHP. Its either the web server's system user name, or the owner of the webroot (through suexec). If owned by the server, its likely `nobody` or `www-data`.

What matters most is what user *PHP* (server side) is running as. [Try this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getpwuid.php) to find out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `echo shell_exec('whoami');`
And that will output the name of the user.  For me, it outputted `apache`

And yes, apache will own the files.  For example, if you do something like this as root:

```
root@localhost# cp /home/user/foo /home/user/foo2
root@localhost# ls -l /home/user
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user       232 Apr  12 12:00 foo
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root       232 Apr  12 12:01 foo2
```

Comment: No, apache will _not_ always own the files. There is such a thing as suexec :) When you copy a file as root, _root_ owns the destination file, as _root_ created it.

Comment: kool, I ran <code>echo exec('whoami');</code> and it returned my ftp user. thanks.